# How to add the Shipping Charge on the selected products in commerce kickstart?

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal commerce kickstart. Can anyone tell  me how to create the field for Shipping charge in the product creation form and I could enter the Shipping charge in that field for selected products.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of modules for it:

- [Commerce Shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping)

> Commerce Shipping provides a shipping rate calculation system for
>   Drupal Commerce, integrating shipping service selection into both the
>   checkout form and order edit form.

- [Commerce Shipping Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_field)